# Careers showing last position in header

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Is there a way to prevent the last position from appearing in the head of the CV profile? It seems a bit strange that even if we're not working at some place at the moment, it still shows up in the header.

I believe the header should show that the person is free for work if there is no **current position**. Or at least give the user the possibility to choose what to write in the subheader (below the name).

Comment: Migrate to [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Cupcake I guess yes, I thought that the careers question should be put here since it's under the stackoverflow section in the "Current community" menu.

Comment: Careers questions are fine here; I know it's kind of confusing, but we check both places and I think it makes more sense here.